# Why is the square of a differential operator not evaluated automatically?

Tags: functions, operators

I defined an operator:

```
py[f_[x, y]] := (I*h*D[f[x, y], y] - x) // Expand
```

(not important, but it represents a simplified component of a quantum momentum in a magnetic field). 
This works:

```
py[f[x, y]]
```

yielding

[image]

This does not:

```
py[py[f[x, y]]]
```

[image]

Why?

Comment: The pattern matches only if the argument of `py` is a function with arguments that are exactly  `x` and `y`.

Comment: @QuantumDot  So, how should I extend the definition, so that my case would also be accounted for?

Comment: I would do something like this: `py = (I h D[#, y] - x &)`

Comment: I need a little more info:  are `py[x]` and `py[y]` (without `f` in them) supposed to vanish?  If so, the construction by @chuy won't work

Comment: true, what result do you want for `py[py[f[x,y]]`?

Answer (score 4):

Your definition of the momentum operator is incorrect because as a **linear operator** it needs to have the function `f` appearing linearly in *all* terms. This includes the `x` in your definition.

To fix this, I would define the operator as follows (using `ψ` instead of `f`):

```
py = Function[ψ, Expand[-I D[ψ, y] + ay[x, y] ψ]];

ay[x_, y_] := x

py@py@ψ[x, y]
```

> $$x^2 \psi (x,y)-2 i x \,\psi ^{(0,1)}(x,y)-\psi ^{(0,2)}(x,y)$$

Here, I added a minus sign to your derivative to make it consistent with quantum mechanics, and left the definition of the vector potential unspecified in `py`. I define it only after defining `py`. Note that `ay[x, y] ψ` appears, not just `ay[x, y]`.

Also, since you have implicitly decided to use `x` and `y` as the global differentiation variables, it's simply not necessary to explicitly include them as a pattern to be matched by the operator. This is why I define the operator as a `Function` where the wave function appears only as a single variable `ψ`.

As you can see, the square of the operator is now evaluated correctly using `py@py`.

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

Based on [Jens](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/245/jens)' [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/110969/29734), I am adapting the code. The idea is the same, but it calculates the derivative correctly:

```
ClearAll@py
SetAttributes[py, HoldFirst]
py[f_[x_, y_], order_] := Expand@Nest[I h D[#, y] - x # &, f[x, y], order]
```

Usage:

```
ClearAll@f
py[f[x, y], 2]
(* x^2*f[x, y] - 2*I*h*x*Derivative[0, 1][f][x, y] - h^2*Derivative[0, 2][f][x, y] *)

f[x_, y_] := x^3 y^3
py[f[x, y], 2]
(* -6 h^2 x^3 y - 6 I h x^4 y^2 + x^5 y^3 *)
```

**Original Post**

Here. Instead of using `f_[x, y]` as the pattern for the argument of `py`, just use a general expression and take the derivative with respect to it, while putting in the variables explicitly as arguments.

```
ClearAll@py
py[expr_, {x_, y_}] := (I*h*D[expr, y] - x) // Expand
py[expr_, {x_, {y_, order_}}] := Nest[py[#, {x, y}] &, expr, order]
```

Usage:

```
py[f[x, y], {x, y}]
py[py[f[x, y], {x, y}], {x, y}]
(* -x + I h Derivative[0, 1][f][x, y] *)
(* -x - h^2 Derivative[0, 2][f][x, y] *)
```

or

```
py[f[x, y], {x, {y, 1}}]
py[f[x, y], {x, {y, 2}}]
py[%, {x, {y, 1}}]
(* -x + I h Derivative[0, 1][f][x, y] *)
(* -x - h^2 Derivative[0, 2][f][x, y] *)
(* -x - I h^3 Derivative[0, 3][f][x, y] *)
```

---

Alternatively, if you don't want to have to put the variables in explicitly, you could do this. This does not allow you to call `py` on the expression after you've evaluated it, but that's why we build in a certain number of derivatives to begin with.

```
ClearAll@py
SetAttributes[py, HoldFirst]
py[f_[x_, y_], order_] := Nest[I h D[#, y] - x &, f[x, y], order]
```

Usage:

```
f[x_, y_] := x^3 y^3
py[f[x, y], 3]
(* -x - 6 I h^3 x^3 *)

ClearAll@f
py[f[x, y], 3]
(* -x - I h^3 Derivative[0, 3][f][x, y] *)
```